# Can we prove this $p$-norm like inequality?

Tags: inequality

Let $z_1,\dots,z_n$ be $n$ real numbers with $n \ge z_i \ge 1$ for all $i$. I can show that
$$
\left(\sum_{i =1}^n (z_i^2-1)\right)^k \ge \sum_{i =1}^n (z_i^{2k}-1),
$$
for all $k \ge 1$ by induction on $k$. But I wonder if there is a way to prove this directly without induction.

Note that if we remove the $-1$ this is just the [lp-norm inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Relations_between_p-norms).

---

NOTE: The inequality is not true as it's stated above. See the accepted answer below. But I do believe it should be true if we further assume $z_i$ are integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality does not hold if $n \ge 2$ and $k > 1$. As a counter-example, choose $z_1 = \ldots = z_n = \sqrt x > 1$.
Then your inequality becomes
$$
 n^k(x-1)^k \ge n(x^k - 1) \, .
$$
But the difference
$$
 f(x) = n^k(x-1)^k - n(x^k - 1)
$$
satisfies $f(1) = 0$ and $f'(1) < 0$, so that $f(x) < 0$ at least in some
interval $(1, 1 + \varepsilon)$.

Comment: But I assumed that $z_i \ge 1$ for all $i$.

Comment: @ablmf: You are right, my fault. – But then your claim is wrong at least for $n=1$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot to add $z_i \le n$. That's what I meant.

Comment: @ablmf: It is still wrong, see update.

Comment: you're right, this does not work for real numbers. I implicitly assumed that $z_i$'s are integers. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.